# Using collide_widget so widgets don't overlap, what is the best solution here?

Tags: kivy

I have a character that runs around the screen, and an image of a tree.  I have collide_widget working so that when the character runs into the tree, it returns True.  The problem is that I am trying to stop the character from running over the tree, the tree should be blocking the characters movement.  What I have tried to do was stop the characters movement to the left, when running into the tree from the left.  When I do this it works and I can then use the up, down or, right key to run away from the tree.  However, if I use this code for all directions, it prevents me from being able to walk away from the tree in any direction once the collide_widget(tree) is True.  I understand the problem, but I am not sure the solution.  Is there a better way to do this?  Here is part of the code.  Is there maybe away to just stop movement before the collision happens?

```
def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):

        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            print self.pos
            print self.app.tree.pos
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/left.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.20
            if self.x < (Window.width * .25):
                bglayout.x += 4
            else: #collide widget code
                if self.collide_widget(self.app.tree) 
                    self.x -= 0
                else:
                    self.x -= 6
        elif keycode[1] == 'right':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/right.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.20
            if self.x > (Window.width * .70):
                bglayout.x -= 4
            else:
                self.x += 6
        elif keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/right.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.20
            if self.y < (Window.height * .25):
                bglayout.y += 4
            else:
                self.y -= 6
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/back.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.1
            if self.y > (Window.height * .70):
                bglayout.y -= 4
            else:
                self.y += 6
        else:
            return False
        return True

    def on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/left1.png'
        elif keycode[1] == 'right':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/right1.png'
        elif keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/right1.png'
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/back2.png'
        else:
            return False
        return True
```

Answer (score -1):

you can copy x and y first (to previous x and previous y perhaps), move the player, check if collideWidget is true, and if so, assign the old values from before you moved and it will be like nothing happened.